# Validation function does not display errors

Tags: javascript

I'm making a validation function (`check`), which displays errors when necessary (`patternMismatch`, `valueMissing`).

The error messagges I want to generate do get displayed on`blur`, but if the function with the same parameters is run on`submit` the error messagges do not get displayed.

I had some trouble passing the variable (var `e_space` - location where the msg should be displayed) to the function, but I fixed it (at least I'm not getting any more error messagges). I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd6s7uf3/4/) to demonstrate the problem but I am having the same issue with the variable/location as I did on my local version. I don't know how to fix it in fiddle.

Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

TLDR: I have a function `check` which should display error msgs in var `e_space`, but the errors are not displayed.

```
const submit_btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn");
submit_btn.addEventListener("click", check);

const form = document.getElementById("form");

function patternText(input){

    if(input.matches('[type="text"]')){
        if(input.validity.patternMismatch){
            if(e_space){
                e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
                input.classList.add("b-r");
            }
            input.classList.add("input-red");
        }
    }
}

function patternTel(input){

    if(input.matches('[type="tel"]')){
        if(input.validity.patternMismatch){
            if(e_space){
                e_space.textContent = "This field must contain 9 numbers.";
                input.classList.add("b-r");
            }
            input.classList.add("input-red");
        }
    }
}

var e_space;

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

function check(){
    inputs.forEach(function(input){
        if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false){
            form.submit();
        }else{
            const e_space = input.closest("div").querySelector(".error");
            patternText(input); //error msg does not get displayed
            patternTel(input); //error msg does not get displayed
            console.log("error")
            return false;
        }

    })
}
```

```
<form id="form" name="form">
  <label for="surname">Surname:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
    <div class="error" id="e_surname"></div>
  </div>
  <label for="tel">Phone number:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
  <div>
    <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" required placeholder="Please enter your Phone number" pattern="[0-9]{9}" />
    <div class="error" id="e_tel"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" >
</form>
```

Comment: you're adding classes and not removing it in that function.. instead of `input.classList.add("input-red")` try `input.className="input-red"`

Comment: also what do you mean error message? I don't see `alert` or `console.log`s anywhere *shrugs*

Comment: Hello. thank you for the reply. I ment my error messagges (ie. `tel` input may only contain numbers). The problem is not with adding/removing classes. The problem I am having is that the messagges in `e_space` are not being displayed. Edit I also have a function which removes the classes, I just didn't add it here as it is not relavent to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that `e_space` had var declared inside the `forEach` statement. Removing it fixed the issue.

```
function check(){
    inputs.forEach(function(input){
        if (input.validity.valueMissing === false && input.validity.patternMismatch === false){
            form.submit();
        }else{
            e_space = input.closest("div").querySelector(".error"); //removed var here
            validate(input);
            console.log("error")
            return false;
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simplified example:

```js
const patternFail = (input) => {
  if (document.querySelector(`#e_${input.id}`) !== null) {
    let e_space = document.querySelector(`#e_${input.id}`);
    if (!input.checkValidity()) {
      if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
        e_space.innerHTML = input.dataset.error;
      }
      if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
        e_space.innerHTML = 'This field is required!';
      }
      input.classList.add("b-r");
      input.classList.add("input-red");
    }
  }
}
const check = () => {
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    patternFail(input);
  });
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    form.submit();
  }
}
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const submit_btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn");
submit_btn.addEventListener("click", check);
```

```css
label>div {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.c-r {
  color: red;
}
.c-g {
  color: green;
}
.b-r {
  border-color: red;
}
.input-red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(204, 59, 59);
}
.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form">
  <label for="surname">Surname:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="surname" data-error="This field can only contain letters from a-z." name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
    <div class="error" id="e_surname"></div>
  </div>
  <label for="tel">Phone number:<span class="asterx">*</span></label>
  <div>
    <input type="tel" id="tel" data-error="This field must contain 9 numbers." name="tel" required placeholder="Please enter your Phone number" pattern="[0-9]{9}" />
    <div class="error" id="e_tel"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">
</form>
```